# how to remove namespace on datamember?

Tags: c#, wcf

I don't have the code with me but basically what I have is a wcf datacontract having about 20 datamember which each one is a custom type.

when sent over the wire, I have

```
      <datamembername namespace>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
      <datamembername>
      <datamembername namespace>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
      <datamembername>
      <datamembername namespace>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
            <few properties here>
      <datamembername>
```

how could I remove the namespace on the datamember?

in one case I return a huge list of that datacontract and 80% of the packet is the namespace.

bandwidth is a problem for me in that case.

Comment: You can't remove the namespace unless there is no namespace on the member.

Comment: @John Saunders, so if on my custom type i specify this: [DataContract(Namespace = "")] it should work? (i can only test tomorrow)

Comment: That's one way to do it. What's the containing element? If you put that into the same namespace as the collection members, then there will only be one namespace declaration, on the containing element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by doing this

```
     [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
```

on my custom class, it removed what I needed.